# Guardar datos en archivos

Tags: c++

Necesito poder guardar varios datos en un .txt

Pero no se como hacer porque al momento de guardar me guarda símbolos y no lo que quiero

Así esta: `fprintf (archivo, "%s", cliente, "%d", apartamento, "%d", npiso)`

`cliente` es un `string`

`apartamento` y `npiso` son `int`

Comment: Monpeco te ha respondido correctamente. Si sigue fallando, es que tu variable `cliente` no es correcta. Muestra mas código; en concreto, la parte en la que asignas valor a las variables.

Answer (score 1):

Se está utilizando de forma incorrecta `fprintf`

`fprintf (archivo, "%s", cliente, "%d", apartamento, "%d", npiso)`

se debe utilizar de la siguiente manera:

`fprintf (archivo, "%s%d%d", cliente, apartamento, npiso)`

Es decir, se tiene que colocar todos los formatos de impresión en el segundo parámetro, y luego colocar las variables correspondientes.

Comment: Si de esa forma ya lo hice y sigue igual

Comment: El problema debe estar en el valor que contienen las variables, tal como dice @Trauma. ¿Probaste imprimiendo las variables antes con un` printf`? es bueno que intentes eso con cada una de las variables por separado.

Answer (score 1):

#### Uso.

La función [`fprintf`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) forma parte de las librerías C adaptadas a C++ y reside en la cabecera [`<cstdio>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio), la firma de la función es la siguiente:

```
int fprintf( std::FILE* archivo, const char* formato, ... );
```

- El parámetro `archivo` debe ser un puntero a manejador de archivo (`std::FILE*`) el cuál se obtiene mediante la función [`fopen`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen), no hay que olvidar cerrar el archivo con `fclose`.
- El parámetro `formato` es una cadena de texto con diferentes especificadores de formato.
- Los parámetros en `...` serán una lista separada por comas de los datos que deben coincidir con los especificadores de formato.

Por lo tanto, tal y como ha mencionado [Monpeco](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/32865/2742) el uso que deberías darle a `fprintf` debería ser:

```
archivo = std::fopen("mi_archivo.txt", "w");
...
...
std::fprintf(archivo, "%s%d%d", cliente, apartamento, npiso);
```

#### Problema.

> Si de esa forma ya lo hice y sigue igual

Es muy probable que la variable `cliente` no tenga datos válidos y sean éstos los que van a parar a tu archivo como *símbolos*.

#### Propuesta.

Olvídate de `fprintf`, usa la librería de streams de C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string cliente{};
    int apartamento{}, npiso{};

    std::cout << "Cliente: ";
    std::cin >> cliente;

    std::cout << "\nApartamento: ";
    std::cin >> apartamento;

    std::cout << "\nPiso: ";
    std::cin >> npiso;

    std::ofstream archivo("mi_archivo.txt");
    archivo << cliente << '\n' << apartamento << '\n' << npiso << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```